# Call multiple JSON data/files in one getJson request

Tags: json, jquery

I have this code:

```
var graphicDataUrl = 'graphic-data.json';
var webDataUrl = 'web-data.json';
var templateHtml = 'templating.html';
var viewG = $('#view-graphic');
var viewW = $('#view-web');

$.getJSON(dataUrls, function(data) {
    $.get(templateHtml, function(template) {
        template = Handlebars.compile(template);
        var example = template({ works: data });        
        viewG.html(example);
        viewW.html(example);
    }); 
});
```

What is the best way for call both webDataUrl and graphicDataUrl JSONs and use their data in order to display them in two different div (#viewG and #viewW)?

Comment: `daataUrls` seems to be undefined.

Comment: Yes, is a placeholder to make others understand what i want to accomplish

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The best way is to do each one individually, and to handle error conditions:

```
$.getJSON(graphicDataUrl)
    .then(function(data) {
        // ...worked, put it in #view-graphic
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // ...didn't work, handle it
    });
$.getJSON(webDataUrl, function(data) {
    .then(function(data) {
        // ...worked, put it in #view-web
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // ...didn't work, handle it
    });
```

That allows the requests to happen in parallel, and updates the page as soon as possible when each request completes.

If you want to run the requests in parallel but *wait* to update the page until they *both* complete, you can do that with [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when):

```
var graphicData, webData;
$.when(
    $.getJSON(graphicDataUrl, function(data) {
        graphicData = data;
    }),
    $.getJSON(webDataUrl, function(data) {
        webData = data;
    })
).then(function() {
    if (graphicData) {
        // Worked, put graphicData in #view-graphic
    }
    else {
        // Request for graphic data didn't work, handle it
    }
    if (webData) {
        // Worked, put webData in #view-web
    }
    else {
        // Request for web data didn't work, handle it
    }
});
```

...but the page may seem less responsive since you're not updating when the first request comes back, but only when both do.

Comment: So now i wrote this: `$.getJSON( graphicDataUrl, function(data){
 $.get( templateHtml, function(template){
  template = Handlebars.compile(template);
  var example = template({ works: data });  
  viewG.html(example);
     });
         });
        $.getJSON( webDataUrl, function(data){
   $.get( templateHtml, function(template){
  template = Handlebars.compile(template);
  var example = template({ works: data });  
  viewW.html(example);
    }); 
         });` But there are lots repeat code! And also can i do it without handle the error? (p.s.there is no better way to write code as replay?)

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta: Of course there's a better way. :-) You can encapsulate that in a function. Why are you re-getting the template from `templateHtml` rather than keeping it and reusing it? (That part seems completely unchanged between the two.)

Answer (score 15):

Just in case it is useful to anyone else who may come across this — and thanks to the Promise advances in jQuery — T.J. Crowder's answer can now be improved into one succinct and general function:

```
/**
 * Load multiple JSON files.
 *
 * Example usage:
 *
 * jQuery.getMultipleJSON('file1.json', 'file2.json')
 *   .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){})
 *   .done(function(file1, file2){})
 * ;
 */
jQuery.getMultipleJSON = function(){
  return jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, jQuery.map(arguments, function(jsonfile){
    return jQuery.getJSON(jsonfile);
  })).then(function(){
    var def = jQuery.Deferred();
    return def.resolve.apply(def, jQuery.map(arguments, function(response){
      return response[0];
    }));
  });
};
```

However the point about not giving any feedback to the user — whilst waiting for the full load — is a good one. So for those that prefer to give responsive feedback, here's a slightly more complicated version that supports progress.

```
/**
 * Load multiple json files, with progress.
 *
 * Example usage:
 *
 * jQuery.getMultipleJSON('file1.json', 'file2.json')
 *   .progress(function(percent, count, total){})
 *   .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){})
 *   .done(function(file1, file2){})
 * ;
 */
jQuery.getMultipleJSON = function(){
  var 
    num = 0,
    def = jQuery.Deferred(),
    map = jQuery.map(arguments, function(jsonfile){
      return jQuery.getJSON(jsonfile).then(function(){
        def.notify(1/map.length * ++num, num, map.length);
        return arguments;
      });
    })
  ;
  jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, map)
    .fail(function(){ def.rejectWith(def, arguments); })
    .done(function(){
      def.resolveWith(def, jQuery.map(arguments, function(response){
        return response[0];
      }));
    })
  ;
  return def;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This code is simple and you can access both response together in one function:

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON(graphicDataUrl),
    $.getJSON(webDataUrl)
).done(function(data1, data2) {
    console.log(data1[0]);
    console.log(data2[0]);
});
```