# Trigger callback after getting multiple json files asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

I have 3 JSON files from an old forum containing: members, topics and replies.
Now I want to render it on a website by getting the 3 json files via javascript/jquery.

I could do it synchronously by first getting members, when returned getting topics and when returned getting replies. But I want to do it asynchronously.

Is there anything like $.getJson that takes multiple URLs and then return an array of results? Like an imaginative $.getJson([url1,url2,url3],callBackFunction)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call multiple JSON data/files in one getJson request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026331/call-multiple-json-data-files-in-one-getjson-request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
var A = $.getJSON(url1);
var B = $.getJSON(url2);
var C = $.getJSON(url3);

$.when(A,B,C).done(function(aResult, bResult, cResult){//when all request are successful
    console.log([aResult[0],bResult[0],cResult[0]]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use something like [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). It allows you to list a series of promises and a callback for when they've all completed. Instead of listing the promises you can also pass an array to `$.when` using `apply`. For example:

```
var endpoints = [url1, url2, url3];
var promises = [];

// Simple function that takes an endpoint and returns a promise.
// I've used $.ajax here, but all of jQuery's
// XHR objects use the promise interface
function getData(endpoint) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
}

// Build an array of promises.
for (var i = 0, l = endpoints.length; i < l; i++) {
  promises.push(getData(endpoints[i]));
}

// Pass the promises to `$.when`. Show the returned data when
// the promises have all finished processing.
$.when.apply(null, promises).then(function (data1, data2, data3) {
  console.log(data1, data2, data3);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As with many jQuery methods, [`$.getJson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) loads data asynchronously. This means that you can call the function and not block execution. As soon as the content has been loaded, it will trigger your callback function.

Given this simple example:

```
console.log( "loading first file..." );
$.getJSON( "file1.js", function( json ) {
  console.log( "first file loaded!" );
});

console.log( "loading second file..." );
$.getJSON( "file2.js", function( json ) {
  console.log( "second file loaded!" );
});

console.log( "loading third file..." );
$.getJSON( "file3.js", function( json ) {
  console.log( "third file loaded!" );
});
```

You will see that all your "loading" console logs will be outputted immediately and the contents of file1/2/3 will start downloading right away.

---

What you could do is have all the callbacks execute the same function which will store a counter of how many resources have been loaded, once all of them have been loaded you can then call your final callback:

```
$.getJSON( "file.js", function( json ) {
  // Do whatever you want with the `json` parameter
  resource_loaded(); // monitor loaded resources.
});

var total_resources = 0
var loaded_resources = 0;
function resource_loaded(){
  loaded_resources += 1;
  if ( loaded_resources === total_resources ){
    final_callback();
  }
}
```